# How to kick off multiple shell scripts at startup

Tags: bash

I have six shell scripts I start when I log in. The shell scripts kick off Python scripts which go out and scrape various things from the net like news headlines, weather info etc., which I add to my desktop via conky.

Problem is starting all of these shell scripts each time is a real pain.

I have looked for and tried some things but nothing seems to work.

Can someone here shed some light on the best way to do this pls.  By the way I can't combine the shell scripts in a single file because they all 'sleep' for a different duration after the initial command is applied.

Thanks.

-- Edit (adding the following comments) --

All of the scripts have the following format:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    python /home/scott/debkaget.py > /home/scott/debka.txt
    sleep 120
done
```

Could that be added to the profile?  I need the sleep aspect to it.  I am running KDE 4.9.

Comment: Do you use a window manager? Which one?

Comment: What is the 'pain'?

Comment: Well the pain is having to open up a terminal, type 'runshell1.sh', ctrl-t, and do this again and again.  And my shell script list keeps growing, 7 now. :(

Comment: I think you should take the 2 parts of my answer and apply it in the locations NormanRamsey indicates.

Comment: I was curious, too, for an explicit example - so I decided to build one.  I'll probably use this myself next time.

Comment: @ScottRichardson Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 4):

If you're "adding to your desktop" you have a window manager running, and if you are using bash it's probably Linux.  In that case you're probably best off launching your scripts into the background from an Xsession file, either `~/.Xsession` or `/etc/X11/Xsession` or a variant.  For more info try

```
man 5 Xsession
man 1 xinit
```

Comment: While I and Leffler presented general purpose answers, this answer has the most domain-specific information.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to add the appropriate invocations to your `.bash_profile` or `.profile` file.  When you run them manually, do you add an `&` at the end to run them in background?  If so, do that in your profile too.

The main issue here is 'what happens if you've already run a login shell'.  Do the 6 scripts behave sanely if there's another copy already running?  Do they bother to detect that there's another copy already running.

If you're logging in at a GUI desktop, then there are ways to run programs when the desktop starts; use it to run the scripts that you're trying to deal with.  For more accurate instructions (from other people), provide more information about your environment.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.  Well to start I am running KDE 4.9, recently moved to this from Ubuntu 12.04.  I was doing the same thing on Ubuntu though.

Comment: Look to the Xsession suggestion by Mr Ramsey.

Answer (score 2):

**You can use this basic strategy:**

- have scripts start by creating pid files as `script_name.pid`.  Make the scripts abort if for their pid file exists
- have scripts run in the background

When you invoke from your .bash_profile (or similar) then the *pid* files will prevent .bashrc from winding up more processes for each new shell.

Per NormanRamsey, you will add to the XSession (or other window manager):

```
# Web Scrapers
runshell_yahoonews.sh
runshell_blog_disney.sh
runshell_stackoverflow_election.sh
runshell_twitter_dad.sh
runshell_twitter_origamistork.sh
runshell_blog_daringfireball.sh
```

Consider writing [bash functions](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-8.html).  You could have a file `lib_scrapers.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash 
pid_path = "~/.X-scrapers/"
suff = '.pid'

function pidfile_create(invoker) {
  if [ ! -e $pid_path$invoker$suff ];
  then
    # make it
    echo $$ > $invoker$suff
  else
    # alert it existance
    cat $pid_path$invoker$suff
  fi
}
function pidfile_destroy(invoker) {
  rm $pid_path$invoker$suff
  if [ -e $pid_path$invoker$suff ];
  then
    echo "$pid_path$invoker$suff could not be destroyed properly"
  fi
}
```

then on line 2 of each of your scrapers (e.g. `runshell_yahoonews.sh`).  This will prevent the script for executing if a scraper is already running.

```
lib_scrapers.sh

if [ pidfile_create($0) ]
then
  exit
fi
```

at the end of each scraper, put

```
pidfile_destroy($0)
```

You could have other tradeoffs, but this sounds reasonable for what you describe.